# ComboBox.setValue after on load sets wrong value

Tags: ajax, extjs, combobox, onload, setvalue

I have combobox which represents login types retreived from serverside. Translation of login types should be done on clientside.

This is example of json returned from serverside:

```
[
  {"valueField":"activeDirectory"},
  {"valueField":"userpass"}
]
```

Combobox is defined like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel : window._i18n['login.login-panel.logintype'],
    itemId : 'logintype',
    store : loginTypesStore,
    name : 'loginType',
    hiddenName: 'hiddenName',
    displayField : 'localizedDisplayField',
    valueField : 'valueField',
    submitValue: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    editable : false,
    allowBlank : false,
    queryMode: 'remote'
})
```

and model and store are defined with:

```
Ext.define('loginTypeModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'valueField' },
        {
            name: 'localizedDisplayField',
            convert: function(value, record) {
                return window._i18n['login.login-panel.logintypename.' + record.get('valueField')];
            }
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'Admin/LoginTypes',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

var loginTypesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: false,
    type: 'json',
    model: 'loginTypeModel'
});
```

I added load listener for store which should set combobox value to the first item received:

```
loginTypesStore.on('load', function () {
    var combo = Ext.getCmp('login-panel').getComponent('logintype');
    console.log('combo.Value : [' + combo.getValue() + '] -> [' + loginTypesStore.data.first().data.valueField + ']');
    combo.setValue(loginTypesStore.data.first().data.valueField); //loginTypesStore.data.first().data.valueField);
    console.log('combo.Value = ' +  combo.getValue());    
});
```

However, in console output I can see this:

```
combo.Value : [null] -> [activeDirectory]
combo.Value = Active Directory EN
```

`"Active Directory EN"` is English translation for `"activeDirectory"` key.

How is that possible?

When I replace store with local one like this:

```
var loginTypesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['valueField', 'localizedDisplayField'],
    data: [
        {"valueField": "userpass", "localizedDisplayField": "Localized userpass"},
        {"valueField": "activeDirectory", "localizedDisplayField": "Localized activeDirectory"}
    ]
});
```

everything is working fine, i.e. in console I see:

```
combo.Value : [null] -> [userpass]
combo.Value = userpass
```

Comment: Could you please post the result of `combo.getStore().getAt(0).get(combo.valueField)`, `combo.getStore().getAt(0).get("valueField")`? I would furthermore recommend to always use the getter methods, not the data property, to access the records and the fields.

Comment: I logged this two statements before and after combo.setValue(...) and result is always "activeDirectory".

What I really want is to submit that value field (not display field). That's why I added hiddenName field, but it is still not submited.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? This sounds like a bug. Make a fiddle and test against different ExtJS versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in reading translation file. Translation `Active directory EN` did actually have invisible `\r` character at the end, and problem was in function `getValue`. From image below, you can see that variable `d` equals to `Active Directory EN` but it has appended `\r`, while `b.getDisplayValue()` does not have it (I debugged and this value is retreived from DOM so maybe that `\r` is lost there).

[image]